# Accessing the Id attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am generating a table and add some fields with jQuery:

```
$('tr[id^="id-"]').prepend("<td><!-- generated by js admin/index.php #498 --><input type='checkbox' name='"+$(this).id+"' id='' class='checkbos_gruppe' /></td>");
```

This part is causing problems:

```
name='"+$(this).id+"'
```

I want to create an element with name of it's parent, so just take the id of the `tr` element.

anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.id` is a DOM property, so it should be just:

```
this.id
```

..instead of `$(this).id`, since it's not a property on the jQuery object.

But, `this` still isn't want you want, it's whatever context you're in, it should be a function to [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) like this:

```
$('tr[id^="id-"]').prepend(function() {
  return "<td><!-- generated by js admin/index.php #498 --><input type='checkbox' name='"+this.id+"' class='checkbos_gruppe' /></td>";
});
```

...or in older versions of jQuery use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead:

```
$('tr[id^="id-"]').each(function() {
  $(this).prepend("<td><!-- generated by js admin/index.php #498 --><input type='checkbox' name='"+this.id+"' class='checkbos_gruppe' /></td>");
});
```